# ffmpeg how to reduce bass and increase treble like audacity

Tags: ffmpeg, audacity

I have an mp3 file. I want to reduce bass and increase treble.
I am trying:

`ffmpeg -y -i original.mp3 -af "treble=g=10" test1.mp3`

but its not same as the effect of Audacity->Effect->bass and treble (increase treble and reduce bass)

below is the image from audacity:

[image]

Answer (score 13):

You could try the firequalizer filter

```
ffmpeg -y -i original.mp3 -af "firequalizer=gain_entry='entry(0,-23);entry(250,-11.5);entry(1000,0);entry(4000,8);entry(16000,16)'" test1.mp3
```

Each entry takes two parameters frequency and gain (dB). The gain for 0 Hz should be the bass value you used. The gain for `16000 Hz` should be the treble value. `1000 Hz` remains as is - no gain. `250 Hz` gain should be half the bass value. `4000 Hz` value should be half the treble value.

Comment: My ffmpeg has no such filter. fireequalizer. any other way

Comment: It's firequalizer with a single `e`. You need a version from March or newer.

Comment: I tweaked it a bit to suit my needs. Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

I like this setting:

```
ffmpeg -y -i original.mp3 -af "firequalizer=gain_entry='entry(0,-8);entry(250,4);entry(1000,-8);entry(4000,0);entry(16000,-8)'" test1.mp3
```